# 3ds rendering problem

Tags: c#

I'm trying to load a 3ds file using TAO framework, and I finally found a 3ds loader that is written in C#.
The loader works fine when I call the rendering Method after setting the matrix as GL_PROJECTION.
But when I try to draw the object after setting GL_MODELVIEW matrix, it turns white .. and the colors can slightly appear in the shaded parts ..

lighting is enabled .. and light posotion is set using glLightfv correctly

I have searched for a ages .. but I found nothing :(

could it be a problem with rendering the 3ds model itself ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe model has some problems with textures, it does not find it in the specified directory

Comment: Thanks for replying :)
But actually I have no compilation Error or exception!!

the main problem is the way my car appears on screen..